# Is this sentence correct grammatically?

Tags: possessives, comparative-constructions, superlatives

I am writing for a contest:

> having a Master degree will give my chances their best to find employment after graduation.

I am especially asking about the word *their*.

Comment: What is *their* supposed to refer to?  I don't understand.

Comment: *"will give my chances their best"* sounds odd to me.

Comment: @DamkerngT. what could it be replaced by please?

Comment: *Having a Master's degree will give me a better chance at finding employment...*

Comment: @Jim please write an answer to accept it. also, i asked another question, please check it

Answer (score 2):

If I look at the following sentence I see several ways to fill in the blank. Note the change to an uppercase `H` and from `Master degree` to [`master's degree`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master%27s_degree).

> Having a master's degree will _________ to find employment after graduation.

Some options that use *chances* or *chance*:

- improve my chances
- give me the best chance
- better my chances

You asked about the usage of *their* when referencing the chances. I could see using:

> My chances were at their best when I stopped speaking.